# Bug in snake game where every time I die, my snake's speed changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a snake game, and there's a setting to change the speed on it. When I change the speed, it works until you die but then changes to something else.

[jsFiddle fullscreen game](https://jsfiddle.net/usr_pyth/3ujzsq9a/embedded/result)

[the code](https://jsfiddle.net/usr_pyth/3ujzsq9a/)

The code I think is relevant:

```js
//sleep function
function sleep(ms) {
 return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
//speed selectors
$('.speedSel').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  if (id == 'slow') {
    moveTimer = 85;
  } else if (id == 'med') {
    moveTimer = 75;
  } else if (id == 'fast') {
    moveTimer = 65;
  } else if (id == 'veryfast') {
    moveTimer = 55;
  } else if (id == 'crazy') {
    moveTimer = 35;
  } else if (id == 'nm') {
    moveTimer = 25;
  }
  console.log(id);
  console.log(moveTimer);
});
//Initialize, run every time you restart the game
function init() {
  snake = [{
    x: canv.width / 2,
    y: canv.height / 2
  }];
  for (var i = 0; i < startLength - 1; i++) {
    snake.push({
      x: snake[i].x + snakeSegWidth,
      y: snake[i].y
    });
  }
  //Run gameloop
  game();
}
//Gameloop, waits var moveTimer milliseconds(ms) then moves
async function game() {
  snake = [{
    x: canv.width / 2,
    y: canv.height / 2
  }];
  for (var i = 0; i < startLength - 1; i++) {
    snake.push({
      x: snake[i].x + snakeSegWidth,
      y: snake[i].y + snakeSegWidth
    });
  }
  placeApple();
  gameOver = false;
  paused = false;
  $("#gamedone").hide();
  while (gameOver == false) {
    //Sleep function
    await sleep(moveTimer);
    if (paused == false) {
      move();
    }
  }
  snake.forEach(clearSnakePart);
  gameIsOver();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Select a Speed</legend>
  <input class='speedSel' type="radio" name="radio" id="slow">
  <label class='speedSel' for="slow">Slow</label>
  <input class='speedSel' type="radio" name="radio" id="med">
  <label class='speedSel' for="med">Medium (Default)</label>
  <br>
  <input class='speedSel' type="radio" name="radio" id="fast">
  <label class='speedSel' for="fast">Fast</label>
  <input class='speedSel' type="radio" name="radio" id="nm">
  <label for="nm">Nightmare</label>
</fieldset>
```

Sorry there's so much, but I really have no clue what is going wrong. The issue is that dying changes how long the sleep timer waits, but doesn't change the `moveTimer` variable.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It's ~300 lines of code, not 20 as that website says. I don't think it qualifies as 'small'

Comment: The same techniques apply. Learning how to debug code is a critical skill to obtain as you learn how to write code. 300 lines of code is small. Most commercial software is tens or hundreds of thousands of lines of code. And even when working on those, you focus on a smaller part and use the same debugging techniques.

Comment: "It's ~300 lines of code, not 20 as that website says. I don't think it qualifies as 'small'", You're correct. For most of us that qualifies as tiny and in some cases nothing more than a function. So... what @Code-Apprentice said.